# puppet agent environment

Tags: puppet

I was reading [puppet doc for environment](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/environments_creating.html) and want clarification in this particular statement:

> When that node requests a catalog from the master, it requests that environment. If you are using an ENC and it specifies an environment for that node, it overrides whatever is in the config file.

Does this mean even if my node is asking for catalog from production env, if the same node is present is another env, master will assign the catalog to node?? As per my knowledge it should give error.

Comment: Is that document public? Could you link to it?

Comment: Check in this doc https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/environments_creating.html

Comment: Clear.....thanks

Comment: I have posted another question on puppet. If you could clarify on that as well.

Comment: I'm re-writing these comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the node cannot know about the ENC, since it is external to the node and it's agent. What this is saying is that if you are using an ENC on the Master, it doesn't matter what environment you set in your node's puppet.conf file, it will send the catalog defined by the ENC.

From the page you linked to: "Note: The value from the ENC is authoritative, if it exists. If the ENC doesn’t specify an environment, the node’s config value is used."

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/environments_creating.html